# Context Menu Item is not showing when form is running

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have created context menu item on windows forms application. But when i run the application and when i try to right click, created menu item is not showing up

[image]

My Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should assign it to `ContextMenuStrip` property of form.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to set the `ContextMenuStrip` property on your form or whatever control you want it to be associated with:

[image]

Comment: Not helped in my case.

Comment: @Mi1anovic your comment likewise is not too helpful.

Comment: Well I aded ContextMenuStrip do a Windows Form. I set the property as you showed. However in the Design view and when I run the app the contextmenustrip is not visible. It's not even working with right click. The only option how can I see it is to click on it within the VS Design view, under the form in a separate section above Output. I removed it and added but not helped. Restart VS not helped. It's enabled.